# "which we call the X" vs. "which we call it the X"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Which of the following sound correct:

> 1. We create a new model which we call the "X" model

Vs.

> 2. We create a new model which we call it the "X" model

Comment: What do you believe "it" in the second sentence provides?

Comment: @Davo -- Both examples try to combine two statements:  "We create a new model."  "We call it the X model."  The second half of example 2 can stand on its own.

Comment: The "it" is unnecessary. I'm not good enough at grammar to explain how, but the second sentence is wrong and the first is right.

Answer (score -1):

Which of the following sound correct:
**We create a new model which we call the "X" model**  Vs.
**We create a new model which we call it the "X" model**

---

**Both sound wrong**

We **create** a new model **which we call** the "X" model.

**create** and **call** do not match,

**and** is not needed or wanted.

We call is **exclusive** only you (your group) will call it....... as opposed to it will be called, Its name

---

We **will create** a new model, which **will be called** the "X" model.

or

We **have created** a new model, which **is called** the "X" model..

---

Alternatively change the which for it.

We **will create** a new model, it **will be called** the "X" model.

or

We **have created** a new model, it **is called** the "X" model

Comment: No electricity so links not complete